# Hibernate: generated Id remains in a not persistent entity after SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

**Hello, everybody!**

Some time ago I run into a trouble: if save method of repository fails, identifier, injected to a bean by Hibernate, remains in the bean. That behaviour may led us to a situation, when we will think about our not persistent bean as about persistent one. I would be pleased to know what practice is common to avoid this situation.

Example test(spring boot + hibernate + oracle database):

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "TEST_ENTITY_GENERATOR", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "TEST_ENTITY_SEQ")
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TEST_ENTITY_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

@Repository
public interface TestEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, Long> {

}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RemainingIdTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityRepository testEntityRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        TestEntity entity = new TestEntity();
        try {
            Assertions.assertThat(entity.getId()).isNull();
            testEntityRepository.save(entity);
            Assertions.fail("Save must fail");
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            Assertions.assertThat(entity.getId()).isNotNull();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to use `org.hibernate.event.spi.PreInsertEventListener` where we can bind the transaction with a processor that will clear your entity if transaction is failed.

Example:

```
@Component
public class IdentifierCleaner implements PreInsertEventListener {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_INSERT).appendListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent event) {
        Object entity = event.getEntity();
        event.getSession().getActionQueue().registerProcess(((success, session) -> {
            if (!success) {
                event.getPersister().resetIdentifier(
                        entity,
                        event.getId(),
                        event.getPersister().getVersion(entity),
                        event.getSession()
                );
            }
        }));
        return false;
    }
}
```